# Non-split central extension of Z by a finite simple non-abelian group

Tags: group-theory, group-extensions

Is there a non-split central extension of an infinite cyclic group by a finite simple non-abelian group?

I have tried, very naïvely, I know, to just take a presentation of $A_5$, say $\langle x,y|x^2=y^3=(xy)^5=1 \rangle$, and then change it this way $\langle x,y,z|x^2=y^3=(xy)^5=z \rangle$. As you probably would see at first glance, this way one ends up with a non-split central extension of a finite(!) group by $A_5$.

So, is there a way of getting such extension? Is there a way of modeling presentations in a wiser manner to get what we want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $E$ be a group with infinite cyclic normal subgroup $N$ and $G/N$ a finite nonabelian simple group (or any finite perfect group). Since $|E:Z(E)|$ is finite, a theorem of Schur says that the commutator subgroup $[E,E]$ is finite, and hence $[E,E] \cap N = 1$.

But $E/N$ perfect implies $E = [E,E]N$, so $E = [E,E] \times N$ is a split extension, and the answer to your question is no.

Comment: That totally makes sense, thanks. Does something similar hold for extensions in general, I mean, for non-split extensions which are not central? I see that the Schur's Theorem argument cannot be used there.

Comment: Since the automorphism group of an infinite cyclic group has order $2$, any extension in which $N$ is infinite cyclic and $G/N$ is perfect must be a central extension. But if you allow $N \cong {\mathbb Z}^k$ then you can get nonsplit extensions.

Comment: @DerekHolt this is true when we have finite quotient $G/N$ right?

Comment: @Dinisaur Sorry, but I have no idea what you are asking - please clarify.

Comment: I was asking if the fact that any extension $G$ of a perfect group $H$ by an infinite cyclic group $N$ must be central requires the group $H$ to be finite (I think I messed up a bit the notation w.r.t. the previous comments/answer). I was aking because I had in mind a non-split central extension with simple quotient and infinite cyclic kernel.

Comment: The fact that it is a central extension does not require $H$ to be finite. That follows from the fact that ${\rm Aut}(N)$ has order $2$. But my argument that the extension splits as a direct product only works when $H$ is finite.